# How to know what events will trigger when doing specific operation in VIM?

Tags: vim

I am studying VIM events, but I found some events may not working well like `##TabLeave` won't be triggered when using `gt/gT` to switch between tabpages. What can I do to know what event has been triggered by VIM when I am doing a specific operation, like typing `tabmove` command to execute it? I am writing a plugin to make my VIM tabpage can source back to previously visited tabpage, but the problem is `tabmove` command won't trigger anything, anyone can help me on this?

```
function! catchSomeEventTriggerByTabmCmd()
let histCmd = histget('cmd', -1)
if match(histCmd, '^tabm') == 0
DoUpdateJumpQueue()
endif
endfunction
```

Comment: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Debugging_window_autocommands

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for sharing this link, this helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

> ... I found some events may not working well like ##TabLeave won't be triggered when using 'gt/gT' to switch between tabpages.

`gt`/`gT` does trigger `TabLeave`. example:

```
:let g:foo = 1
:autocmd TabLeave * let g:foo = g:foo + 1 | echom "TabLeave Event " . g:foo
:tabnew
```

Now do a few `gt`/`gT`'s. You should get messages

> What can I do to know what event has been triggered by VIM when I am doing a specific operation, like typing 'tabmove' command to execute it? I am writing a plugin to make my VIM tabpage can source back to previously visited tabpage, but the problem is 'tabmove' command won't trigger anything, anyone can help me on this?

I am not sure you can use an event/autocmd like `TabLeave` to capture anything from `:tabmove`. It probably is also going to be tricky to use tab page numbers as well, since `:tabmove` modifies them.

Luckily, Vim always has to focus a window, so instead of trying to have a history of tab pages, maybe have a history have window id's. You may be able to use `win_getid()` and `win_gotoid()` to accomplish your history behavior.

For more help see:

```
:h win_getid()
:h win_gotoid()
:h windowid
```

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks sincerely for your answer, yes, I was wrong, the gt/gT does trigger the event #TabLeave. and I have figured out a way to track the tabmove command even it didn't trigger any tabpage related event. My way is to store the tabpage number by predefined function tabpagenr() when the #TabEnter event comes, and then compare it with the tabpage number when #TabLeave event, because when switching tabpages, these 2 number should always stay the same, but if there is a tabmove command between, then it's not. So basically, according to this point, then we can know it. Thanks anyway!